# How to test an action gets called in a component ember testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

How can I test that an action was called in a component?

There are multiple ways of triggering an action like clicking on a button. Now I want to test that the action that is called when clicking on that button is actually called. Something like `expect.functionName.to.be.called` or something.

I have the following code

```
test('it closes the create dialog when close btn is clicked', function(assert) {
  this.render(hbs`{{group-create cancelCreateAction="cancelAction"}}`)

  this.$('button.btn--primary').click()
  expect('myAction').to.be.called?
})
```

so i'm just wondering what I can do there?

Answer (score 1):

Well your action does something we don't know. But here's a small test i have written checking some DOM elements and the current route. Hard to tell without you telling us what your action does.

```
click('.someSavingButton');

   andThen(function() {
     assert.equal(currentRouteName(), 'index');
     assert.equal(find('.something-new-in-the-dom').length, 1, "New item in HTML");
```

Comment: Can't do stuff like this in ember 2.1.0. How are you importing `click` and `andThen` functions?

Comment: import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';

Comment: you're still going to get an undefined for `andThen` and `click`. Where do you import that from?

Comment: I have written these tests 3 months ago they used to worked perfectly back then. https://gist.github.com/kristjanreinhold/d62616b921c5bac042ba Here's a full test. Is it not working nowadays ?

Comment: Not sure what test framework you're using or if this is v1.10.0 or something, because we need explicit imports for `click`, `andThen`. It won't just work like that. You can try updating to v2.1.0 and seeing if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while also searching for a way to test bubble up actions in an integration test (instead
of closure actions). Maybe you already found a solution, but I will answer to have the next person find it earlier than me.

The idiomatic way to test if an action was called is to write a mock function and assert that it will be called.
In your example - before closure actions - the way to write this kind of test is as follows:

```
test('it closes the create dialog when close btn is clicked', function(assert) {
  // make sure our assertion is actually tested
  assert.expect(1);

  // bind the action in the current test
  this.on('cancelAction', (actual) => {
    let expected = { whatever: 'you have expected' };
    assert.deepEquals(actual, expected);

    // or maybe just an assert.ok(true) - but I am not sure if this is "good" style
  });

  this.render(hbs`{{group-create cancelCreateAction="cancelAction"}}`)

  this.$('button.btn--primary').click()
  expect('myAction').to.be.called?
});
```

Nowadays, with the closure action paradigm, the correct way to bind the mock function would be

```
// bind the action in the current test
this.set('cancelAction', (actual) => {
  let expected = { whatever: 'you have expected' };
  assert.deepEquals(actual, expected);
});

this.render(hbs`{{group-create cancelCreateAction=(action cancelAction)}}`)
```